# recreate file from group of byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose there is a file called **input.zip** in my folder.

I want to transfer this file from a client to a server, so what I'm currently doing is:

```
//client side
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.zip");
while(fis.read(buffer) > 0) { ... }
```

In a nutshell: Inside the client, I separate the file in a lot of byte arrays using `FileInputStream.read(buffer)`.

I send each of these arrays to the server and the server know the index of each of the arrays (i.e., the first array will have index 0, the second will have index 1, and so on).

Given that in the server side I have all the byte arrays and I know the order they were sent, I want to build a big byte array to store them all.

How can I build this big byte array and write the file (that should be equals to **input.zip**) in a file called **output.zip**?

Comment: Just write them to a FileOutputStream? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: @thatotherguy I changed the question a little bit, I wasn't clear enough. I'm confused at how I should build the big array given all small arrays. Using FileOutputStream is a bit complicated because the arrays come at random time, I'm using UDP transference and threads.

Comment: In your question, you're saying: "I have all the byte arrays and I know the order they were sent". So, write them, in the order they were sent, to a FileOutputStream (if you want to create a file), or to a ByteArrayOutputStream (if you want to create a byte array). If you actually don't have all the arrays on the server, but instead receive them in separate threads, in a random order, then change your question, explain what is the actual problem and post the relevant server code.

Comment: @Daniel You can use a `RandomAccessFile` to `seek` to the right byte position and `write` the data there whenever you get a new region

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with.

Comment: In any case, if you know up-front how large the file is, you can create one byte array of the right size on the server, and when you read the incoming packets, immediately read the data into that big byte array , at the right offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InputStream and OutputStream are processed sequentially.

```
for (;;) {
    int nread = fis.read(buffer);
    if.(nread <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    fos.write(buffer, 0, nread);
}
```

The last read buffer not entirely filled.

The utility class Files will do that and more.

```
Path path = Paths.get(“...“);
Files.copy(path, fos);
```

Comment: should I use the lines `Path path ... ; Files.copy ...` before the `for` ?

Comment: No the for-code is the "repair" of the given code. However alternatively one needs only two lines to copy a file (Path) to an OutputStream. `Path` is a newer, more general concept for File (which only is for the file system). `Files` is a class worth knowing.